# mongoose schema field associate array

Tags: mongoose, associative-array

My schema looks like:

`var Article = new mongoose.Schema({
    sentenceArray: {}
});`

The purpose of having `sentenceAudioArray: {}` is so that I can add `{sentId,sentText}` tuples to my article. This can be achieved through a standard Array ( `sentenceArray: []` ), but retrieval will not be O(1) (ie, id I know a sentId, I cannot simply call `sentenceArray[sentId]` to retrieve).

In my createArticle methods, I have

```
newArticle.sentenceArray = {};
```

This doesnt seems to create the field in mongo. When I look at the database, this field sentenceArray is not created. Consequently, when I do

```
anArticle.sentenceArray[sentId] = "Some Sentence"
```

I get an error that sentenceArray is undefined.

Any suggestions on how to use Associative Array within a Mongoose schema.

Edit: Please note that the objective is to be able to add multiple sentences to sentenceArray. I expect to call

```
anArticle.sentenceArray["firstSent"] = "Some Sentence";

anArticle.sentenceArray["secondSent"] = "Another Sentence";

anArticle.sentenceArray["thirdSent"] = "Yet Another Sentence";
```

and later on, call

```
console.log(anArticle.sentenceArray["thirdSent"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a default:

```
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sentenceArray: { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default : {} }
});
```

The `Mixed` type tells Mongoose that `sentenceArray` (which is really an object, not an array) is a *"can hold anything"* property. There are some things to be aware of using this type, so you should [read the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed).

Providing a default will not make Mongoose write empty values of this property to the database, but it will make sure that `sentenceArray` exists when you instantiate a document or retrieve one from the database.

Comment: This does create a sentenceArray={} in the db . But when I do anArticle.sentenceArray[sentId] = "Some Sentence", nothing changes in the db, ie, sentenceArray stays as {}

Comment: yup ... a clarification ... i want to put many sentences in the sentenceArray .. lemme edit the original post

Comment: @Amarsh so before you save the document, after adding an item (or items) to `sentenceArray`, did you use `.markModified()`?